# Correct Template constructor for MBED Callback of member function

Tags: templates, g++, pointer-to-member, incomplete-type, mbed

I am using the mbed library and want to attach a member function to a `Ticker` (calls a callback function on regular interval) which is also a member.  I may have multiples instances of my class and I would like each one to be able to manage its own `Ticker` and to allow the callback function to deal with its respective data.

Code:

```
* header */
class MyClass {
    uint16_t time;
    Ticker ticker;
    void Init();
    void SendMessage();
};

/* source */
void MyClass:: SendMessage() {
}

void MyClass::Init() {
    ticker.attach(Callback<MyClass>(this, &MyClass::SendMessage), time);
}
```

This gives me `invalid use of incomplete type 'class mbed::Callback<MyClass>'`

Why does MyClass need to be complete for a wrapper for a member function pointer?  Am I missing something fundamental, or is too dependent on the `Callback` class implementation?

[`Callback` class](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/Callback.h)

[`Ticker` class](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/drivers/Ticker.h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about `MyClass` being incomplete. It's about `Callback<MyClass>` being incomplete.

The main `Callback` template is left incomplete intentionally. The only specialization in scope is

```
template <typename R>
class Callback<R()>
```

which means you need to pass it a function type, and the function must have no arguments. This is called *type erasure*. A callback can be constructed from many different function-like values, but the resulting type is always `Callback <some-plain-function-type>`. It works very much like `std::function`, except `std::function` allows arbitrary function signatures.

Since your callback returns a `void`, you need something like this:

```
ticker.attach(Callback<void()>(this, &MyClass::SendMessage), time);
```

Comment: compiled and tested.  And clarified question title, since it was not actually an incomplete type issue.